# Ошибка CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

Tags: python, django

Добрый всем день! Есть два представления:

```
def RegEnd(request):
    #Здесь совершаем действия по чтению ПОСТ данных
    e_mail = request.POST['e_mail']
    i_name = request.POST['i_name']
    #создаем пользователя
    profile = Profile.objects.create_user(i_name,e_mail)
    profile.save()
    c = {'name': i_name }
    template_name = 'polls/regend.html'
    return render_to_response(template_name, c, RequestContext(request))
```

и

```
def main(request):
    hi = "Вы не авторизованы!"
    return render_to_response('polls/main.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

В 1м представлении используется шаблон с формой:

```html
<form name="eReg" method="POST" action="main"> {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="col-md-12">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group has-warning" style="text-align: center;margin-top: 20px;">
          <label class="control-label" for="succ">
            Введите код регистрации здесь
            <input class="form-control" name="activate" id="succ" type="text" style="width: 150px;">
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
      <label class="control-label" for="succ">
        <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin: 30px;">ДАЛЕЕ</button>-->
        <input type = 'submit' class="btn btn-warning" value = 'ДАЛЕЕ' />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Так вот при переходе к main выскакивает ошибка: CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

В settings.py мидлклассы имеют такой вид:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Что еще может быть не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо render_to_response попробуйте использовать render.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def RegEnd(request):
...
    return render(request, template_name, c)
```

В последних версиях Django параметр context_instance уже убрали, до этого он был deprecated. Соответственно, передать контекст запроса через render_to_response нельзя. А render делает это автоматически.

В этой строке у вас RequestContext передается в качестве другого параметра - content_type

```
return render_to_response(template_name, c, RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Благодарю, с рендером именно в таком виде заработало. Видимо, оно по умолчанию CSRF защиту использует?

Answer (score 1):

исползуйте с csrf только render

> The recommended approach is to use `render` instead of `render_to_response`. The code is simpler, and the CSRF token will work because `render` will uses a request context to render the template.